# Internet Explorer 9 really version 7?

Tags: perl, internet-explorer

I am seeing some funky things with the version of IE on a user's system.
My perl cgi app says the version is 'MSIE 7' and when you click on help,about
in the web browser, it says it's MSIE 9.

Perl Code for browser data:

my $browser_data = $ENV{'HTTP_USER_AGENT'};

Why does it say that IE is version 7 instead of 9??

Thx!!

John

Comment: The user's browser mode is probably set to IE7 in which case the HTTP_USER_AGENT will reflect that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your user has either "Intranet Settings" or "Compatibility View" enabled for your site.

Both of these IE features make IE8 and IE9 pretend to be IE7.

You can tell it's lying, and derive the real version, from the presence of `Trident` in the User-Agent string - see [Understanding user-agent strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: +1 for the right answer. For more info on IEs various modes and how to force it to use the mode you want, see my blog post on the subject: http://spudley.com/blog/keeping-ie-in-standards-mode

Comment: Thanks Richie!!! The user did have the compatibility setting turned on and that was causing the problem.  Thanks for the explanation and link.